# How to send query parameters to POST request from Java client, and receive using @QueryParam

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, query-string

I'm trying to write a basic web service that uses JAX-RS @QueryParam annotation. My Java client sends a POST request using HttpURLConnection. The call is being made to the web service, but the parameters are not getting sent correctly (They remain null). I know there are lot of questions related to this on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find a convincing solution. It'll be great if somebody points out the mistake in the code below.
(I've simplified the code for posting here).

Here's the web service code:

```
@POST
@Path("/notify")
@Consumes("*/*")
public Response notifyUser(@QueryParam("notification") String notification, @QueryParam("applicationName") String applicationName) {
    System.out.println("Notification: " + notification);
    System.out.println("Application: " + applicationName);
    return Response.status(200).entity(notification + " from " + applicationName).build();
}
```

And this is Java client:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
         url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/...");
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
         conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
         OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         params.add(new NameValuePair("notification", "Notification string"));
         params.add(new NameValuePair("applicationName", "MyApp"));
         os.write(getQuery(params).getBytes("UTF-8"));
         os.flush();
         os.close();
         return conn.getResponseCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

My web service is getting called, but the parameter values are received as null. Please help.

Comment: Is this code only for Android JDK or for Windows JDK?

Answer (score 4):

To bind the value(s) of a HTTP query parameter to a resource method parameter using [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html), you need to **send your parameters in the query string of the URL**:

> [**3.4.  Query**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)
>
> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component, serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any). The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.
>
> [...]

By default, in `GET` requests, the parameters are *sent as part of the URL*. In `POST` requests, the parameters are *sent in the body of the request*.

To send *query parameters* in `POST` requests with [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), *append* them to the requested URL, as following:

```java
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new NameValuePair("param1", "value1"));
params.add(new NameValuePair("param2", "value2"));

String query = getQuery(params);
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api" + "?" + query);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

...
```

Answer (score 1):

`@QueryParam` only recognizes parameters which are part of the URL. You need to use `@FormParam` instead in order to read the parameters from the POST body.

Answer (score 1):

Note that rfc2616 is obsolete since 2014, it's replaced by the rfc723x specs. No rfc723x servers exists at this moment

A rfc723x compilant server will respond with status 400:

- When a get request has a message body.
- When a post request has parameters in the request uri.

Creating a server that will accept both are insecure by design.
Uri parameters can and will be forged by a hacker.
When a parameter is in the request uri and in the message body, how to securely handle this situation? Which has precedence?

The only reasonable answer is to reject such a request with status 400. You as a programmer cannot make the distinction between a legal user and a hacker in this situation.

rfc7230 also specifies that parameters may only occur once.
Why? An example:

Who do you vote for?
http://voting.com/?vote=clinton
obviously Clinton

Who do you vote for?
http://voting.com/?vote=trump&vote=clinton
Trump? Clinton? Trump and Clinton?

Who do you vote for?
http://voting.com/?vote=trump&vote=clinton&vote=trump
Trump? Trump 2 times and Clinton 1 time?

rfc2616 servers accept this and return an array of values for vote and are insecure by design on this point.